# How to print each word in a separate line. Each word is capitalized except the first

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I am trying to create a function that prints each word on a new line. The argument given is a string with words that aren't separated by a space but capitalized except the first word i.e. "helloMyNameIsMark".  I have something that works but wondering if there's a better way of doing this in javaScript.

```
separateWords = (string) => {

  const letters = string.split('');
  let word = "";
  const words = letters.reduce((acc, letter, idx) => {
    if (letter === letter.toUpperCase()) {
      acc.push(word);
      word = "";
      word = word.concat(letter);
    } else if (idx === letters.length - 1) {
      word = word.concat(letter);
      acc.push(word);
    } else {
      word = word.concat(letter)
    }
    return acc
  }, []);
  words.forEach(word => {
    console.log(word)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the regex `[A-Z]` and [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) each upper case letter with `\n` prefix

```js
const separateWords = str => str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => '\n' + m)

console.log(separateWords('helloMyNameIsMark'))
```

Or you could use a lookahead `(?=[A-Z])` to `split` at each upper case letter to get an array of words. Then loop through the array to log each word:

```js
const separateWords = str => str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/g)
separateWords('helloMyNameIsMark').forEach(w => console.log(w))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the breaking of words into an array and the printing of that array into two distinct functions.  Regular expressions make that first part much easier than your `reduce` call.  (But that `reduce` is a good thought if you don't see a regex solution.)

My version might look like this:

```js
const separateWords = (str) => str .replace (/([A-Z])/g, " $1") .split (' ')

const printSeparateWords = (str) => separateWords (str) .forEach (word => console.log (word) )

printSeparateWords ("helloMyNameIsMark")
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to adiga's answer, but it can actually be simpler:

```
const separateWords = str => str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '\n$&');
```

This will also benefit from improved performance (might matter if used at scale).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more literal interpretation of your stated requirement: *prints each word* on a new line.

```js
function separateWords(str){
  let currentWord = '';

  for (let chr of str){
    if (chr == chr.toUpperCase()){
      console.log(currentWord);
      currentWord = chr;
    
    } else {
      currentWord += chr;
    }
  }

  if (currentWord)
    console.log(currentWord);
}

separateWords('helloMyNameIsMark');
```